# Java about Array of object

Tags: java

```
Dog[] mydogs = new Dog[3]; 
int x = 0; 
if (x<3) { 
   mydogs[x] = new Dog();
   mydogs[x].size = 12;
   mydogs[x].bark(); //Yip Yip 
   x = x+1;
 }

void bark() { 
    if (size > 60) {
        System.out.println("Woof, Woof ");
    } else if (size > 14) {
        System.out.println("Ruff, Ruff "); 
    } else { 
       System.out.println("Yip, Yip ");
 }
```

I am getting “ Yip Yip “ output, but I am thinking that since (x<3) condition is placed. then should not it print it three times? lie below

Yip, Yip

Yip, Yip

Yip, Yip

Comment: Replace `if` with `while` to loop

Comment: size is instance variable in Dog class

Comment: Use while loop instead if.worked. but how please explain?

Comment: Read about `if` and `while` statements in java

Comment: `if` is a condition, `while` is a loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to basic Java syntax, which should rather be studied via books or tutorials.

Comment: Got it. if statement checks if an expression is true or false, and then runs the code inside the statement only if it is true. The code inside the loop is only run once... A while statement is a loop. Basically, it continues to execute the code in the while statement for however long the expression is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` doesn't cause the condition to be evaluated in a loop. You need to use a loop for that.

```
while (x<3) { 
   //changes made to to mydogs[x] are irrelevant to the execution of the loop
   x = x+1;
}
```

This loop will run continually until the condition `x < 3` evaluates to `false`, which will only happen after `x = x+1` has been executed 3 times. until then, the code inside the loop body will be repeatedly executed.